# Heroku pg:psql insert

Tags: java, sql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have

```
pg:psql
```

into my database on heroku. And I am running this:

`INSERT INTO notes (course, date, name, professor, semester, university) VALUES (math, 23, ayy, lmao, summer, nyu);` and my tables look like:

[image]

But I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR:  column "math" does not exist
LINE 1: ...e, name, professor, semester, university) VALUES (math, 23, ...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "notes.date".
```

Do I have the wrong SQL statement?

Comment: The values that are of string type should be in single quotes. like 'math'.

Comment: use `VALUES ('math'`

Comment: Now I get the error column "math" doesnt exist...

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good if you changed the string values to single qutoes. I would recommend create a new table and try it again, because i cannot see any mistake in query syntax. Maybe you can post your schema.